Using modal verbs
I will do my best to make this question as good as it is only possible this time.
1 He could have said hello to him when they met
2 He could say hello to him when they met
I want to convey the meaning that it is possible that he said "hello" when they met. I think both examples will do.
I think 1 is more related to the present times. We are saying now what we think was possible for him to do when they met. On the other hand 2 in more related to the past what he was able to do then. Is it corrret? And my second question if in 1 we change "could" to "might" the meaning will be almost the same. There is some difference but nothing really visible. I'm concerned with example number 2 I don't think "might" suits that context. But you are here to jugdge. So tell me your thoughts.

Can you please start proofreading your posts? e.g. "On the other hand 2 in more related to the past" and "But you are here to jugdge" Don't you have a spell checker installed in your browser? Red squiggly lines appear whenever a word is misspelled. It won't fix every spelling mistake e.g. "stayed" and "staid" which mean different things but it would be a good start.

You need to be far more specific when describing your desired meaning. "Possible" is a very vague word.  Does you mean to say you can't remember? Or that you weren't paying much attention?  Or he didn't have laryngitis at the time?

Only the first has the meaning you intend, whether you use could or might.
He could say hello to him when they met - He was able to greet him on the occasion(s) when they met.
He might say hello to him when they met - He had the opportunity to do so, and sometimes did.

You state "He might say hello to him when they met - He had the opportunity to do so, and sometimes did.". Thus, it only makes sense when it is some repeated action and it wouldn't work if I wanted to use might for only one time when they met?

If it was only one meeting, you would have to say "He may/might have said hello to him when they met".

1 In the past people should wear uniforms to school 2 when you met him yesterday you should say hello. Does it make sense anywhere to use "should" or only "should have" makes sense here?

No. "You should have said hello" (you didn't, but I think you ought to have done). Should is quite wrong for the first one - "people (children?) had to wear uniform for school".

(1) is correct. (2) is simply wrong, and if you think about it you will see that instinctively you already know this. You wrote, "We are saying now what we think was possible for him to do when they met." Not is possible. You knew that the event happened in the past so you needed to match the tenses. It's the same in your example.
